# calling a function on a non object

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting the error:
Message: layerName parameter is not passed in GetPOI request.
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

here's where i create the PDO $db

```
function connectDb() {
  try {
    $dbconn = 'mysql:host=' . DBHOST . ';dbname=' . DBDATA ; 
    $db = new PDO($dbconn , DBUSER , DBPASS );
    // set the error mode to exceptions
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE , PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     return $db;

      }//try
       catch(PDOException $e) {
    error_log('message:' . $e->getMessage());
  }// catch

}// connectDb
```

and here is where the error occurs:

```
// $sql is returned as a PDO statement object. 
  $sql = $db->prepare( 'SELECT id,
               imageURL,
               title,
               description,
               footnote,
               lat,
               lon,
               (((acos(sin((:lat1 * pi() / 180)) * sin((lat * pi() / 180)) +
                      cos((:lat2 * pi() / 180)) * cos((lat * pi() / 180)) * 
                      cos((:long  - lon) * pi() / 180))
                      ) * 180 / pi()
               )* 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344 * 1000
               ) as distance,
               iconID,
               objectID,
               transformID
              FROM POI
         WHERE POI.poiType = "geo"   
        HAVING distance < :radius
      ORDER BY distance ASC
         LIMIT 0, 50 ' );
```

have I not set up the $db correctly? I can also post the whole script if it helps.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to return `$db`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$db` is not defined by the time you call `$db->prepare()` due to its scope.

It's most likely that `$db>prepare()` is being called inside a function; if that's the case you fix it by passing `$db` as an argument to that function, i.e.

```
function doSomething(\PDO $db)
{
    $sql = $db->prepare('...');
}

$db = connectDb();
doSomething($db);
```

Another potential issue is that an error occurred in `connectDb()`; you only log the error, but the function still returns normally and thus `$db` would still be undefined in the global scope.

Comment: I was just going to make a comment about it most likely being a scope issue, since OP's constants don't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Constants have no scope, so that shouldn't be an issue :)

Comment: @Jack, except class constants. ;-)